# coordinate.latitude error <Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)>

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapkit

I'm trying to use latitude and longitude from a trails database to push to the maps app and and direct users to trailheads from their current location. The API is in JSON format. Here is my custom init method in the model class:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.latitude = dict[@"lat"];
        self.longitude = dict[@"lon"];
        self.name = dict[@"name"];
        self.city = dict[@"city"];
        self.state = dict[@"state"];
        self.country = dict[@"country"];
        self.described = dict[@"description"];
        self.directions = dict[@"directions"];
        self.activities = dict[@"activity_type_name"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Here are that class' coordinates properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *longitude;
```

When the app calls the directToTrail method,the app crashes and the code displays `<Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)>` at the coordinate.latitude assignment. Here is the code for that method which is in my custom cell class.

```
- (void)directToTrail:(Trail *)trail
{


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[trail.latitude doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[trail.longitude doubleValue];


    MKPlacemark *endLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *endingItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];
    NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];
    [endingItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
}



    MKPlacemark *endLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc]     initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *endingItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];
    NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving     forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];
    [endingItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

When I print out coordinate.latitude in the console to see its value, I get 0 and for coordinate.longitude: 1. These are not the values from the API. I *am* getting other data accurately from the API. Why is that not true of the coordinate numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you try to declare the two properties as strong?
Actually NSNumber is a pointer!

Try with:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *longitude;
```

instead of:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *longitude;
```

To tell the truth, in my opinion, is much better to define the two properties as double or CLLocationDegrees (actually typedef double CLLocationDegrees;)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double longitude;
```

or in a more "compact" way as:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```